# Custom lstlisting command changed verbatim font size

Tags: listings, verbatim

I've copied a custom lstlisting command that makes it look like Mathematica code. This is that code below:

```
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{beramono}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{rotating}

\definecolor{identifiercolor}{rgb}{.4,.6,.56}
\definecolor{stringcolor}{gray}{0.5}
\definecolor{inactivecolor}{rgb}{0.15,0.15,0.5}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle={\footnotesize\def\fvm@Scale{.85}\fontfamily{fvm}\selectfont},
  breaklines=true,
  escapeinside={\%*}{*)},
  keywordstyle={\bfseries\color{inactivecolor}},
  stringstyle={\bfseries\color{stringcolor}},
  identifierstyle={\bfseries\color{identifiercolor}},
  language=Mathematica,
  otherkeywords={DiscretizeRegion},
  showstringspaces=false}
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Listing}
```

My Mathematica codes looked great but after I've implemented it, my verbatim environments have changed from
[image: before]

to this

[image: after]

Is there a way I can keep the "Courier new"-like font in verbatim and decrease its size to the "before" state?